Compiling with Windows References on MacOS / Alternative to get Printer Settings?
Using C# and .NET Core 8, I am aware that System.Drawing.Printing is now firmly Windows only.
However this also means I have no access to these symbols/routines at design time or compile time from Linux, meaning that I can no longer compile this application on Linux or Mac.
Obviously we could use SkiaSharp for printing, but this wouldn't give us access to the printer settings like paper sizes and margins. I could wrap the code in an conditional compilation flag, but I would still be limited to compiling on a Windows computer.
I have no problem only running on Windows, we can make that a system requirement.
So, are there any cross platform plugins, workarounds or references I can use to allow me to compile this program on Linux/Mac while targeting Windows, using either System.Drawing.Printing or another mechanism to either get Printer Settings or complete the print out as well?

The following may be of interest: What is .NET MAUI?
